# Обязательно ли в java использовать @OneToMany?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, моделирование, реляционная-модель

У меня есть сущность Сотрудник и много других сущностей, представляющих документы Прием на работу, Заявление на отпуск, и т.п., которые имеют поле `Сотрудник`.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно указать `@ManyToOne` в сущностях документов, и не нужно указывать `@OneToMany` в сущности `Сотрудник`?

Допустим, каскадирование не потребуется по отношению к документам от сотрудника. Наличие всех документов сотрудника в поле `List<Document>` не требуется. Эти выборки нужны только в отдельных формах и отчетах, и там это все можно сделать запросами.

Есть ли какие то причины, в данном случае, все таки использовать поле `List<Document>` с аннотацией `@OneToMany`?

```
public class Document {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Employee employee;
    
    
public class Employee {
// здесь нет поля 
// @OneToMany
// List<Document> documents
```

Answer (score 1):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно указать `@ManyToOne` в сущностях документов, и не нужно указывать `@OneToMany` в сущности Сотрудник?

Правильно, в этом случае устанавливается однонаправленная связь (ассоциация) `@ManyToOne`. Если нужна двухнаправленная, то нужно указывать `@OneToMany` в сущности `Сотрудник`, но не обязательно.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.